# Dialog flow V2 API SDK for .NET platform is not found.

Tags: .net, dialogflow-es

Dialog flow V2 API SDK for .NET platform is not found. Can any one help on this

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2